# recursion vs iteration time complexity

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Could anyone explain exactly what's happening under the hood to make the recursive approach in the following problem much faster and efficient in terms of time complexity?

The problem: Write a program that would take an array of integers as input and return the largest three numbers sorted in an array, without sorting the original (input) array.

For example:

- Input: `[22, 5, 3, 1, 8, 2]`
- Output: `[5, 8, 22]`

Even though we can simply sort the original array and return the last three elements, that would take at least `O(nlog(n))` time as the fastest sorting algorithm would do just that. So the challenge is to perform better and complete the task in `O(n)` time.

So I was able to come up with a recursive solution:

```
def findThreeLargestNumbers(array, largest=[]):

    if len(largest) == 3:
        return largest

    max = array[0]
    for i in array:
        if i > max:
            max = i

    array.remove(max)
    largest.insert(0, max)
    return findThreeLargestNumbers(array, largest)
```

In which I kept finding the largest number, removing it from the original array, appending it to my empty array, and recursively calling the function again until there are three elements in my array.

However, when I looked at the suggested iterative method, I composed this code:

```
def findThreeLargestNumbers(array):
    sortedLargest = [None, None, None]
    for num in array:
        check(num, sortedLargest)
    return sortedLargest

def check(num, sortedLargest):
    for i in reversed(range(len(sortedLargest))):
        if sortedLargest[i] is None:
            sortedLargest[i] = num
            return
        if num > sortedLargest[i]:
            shift(sortedLargest, i, num)
            return

def shift(array, idx, element):
    if idx == 0:
        array[0] = element
        return array
    array[0] = array[1]
    array[idx-1] = array[idx]
    array[idx] = element
    return array
```

Both codes passed successfully all the tests and I was convinced that the iterative approach is faster (even though not as clean..). However, I imported the time module and put the codes to the test by providing an array of one million random integers and calculating how long each solution would take to return back the sorted array of the largest three numbers.

The recursive approach was way much faster (about 9 times faster) than the iterative approach!

Why is that? Even though the recursive approach is traversing the huge array three times and, on top of that, every time it removes an element (which takes `O(n)` time as all other `999` elements would need to be shifted in the memory), whereas the iterative approach is traversing the input array only once and yes making some operations at every iteration but with a very negligible array of size 3 that wouldn't even take time at all!

I really want to be able to judge and pick the most efficient algorithm for any given problem so any explanation would tremendously help.

Answer (score 1):

Advice for optimization.

Avoid function calls.  Avoid creating temporary garbage.  Avoid extra comparisons.  Have logic that looks at elements as little as possible.  Walk through how your code works by hand and look at how many steps it takes.

Your recursive code makes only 3 function calls, and as pointed out elsewhere does an average of 1.5 comparisons per call.  (1 while looking for the min, 0.5 while figuring out where to remove the element.)

Your iterative code makes lots of comparisons per element, calls excess functions, and makes calls to things like `sorted` that create/destroy junk.

Now compare with this iterative solution:

```
def find_largest(array, limit=3):
    if len(array) <= limit:
        # Special logic not needed.
        return sorted(array)
    else:
        # Initialize the answer to values that will be replaced.
        min_val = min(array[0:limit])
        answer = [min_val for _ in range(limit)]

        # Now scan for smallest.
        for i in array:
            if answer[0] < i:
                # Sift elements down until we find the right spot.
                j = 1
                while j < limit and answer[j] < i:
                    answer[j-1] = answer[j]
                    j = j+1
                # Now insert.
                answer[j-1] = i

        return answer
```

There are no function calls.  It is possible that you can make up to 6 comparisons per element (verify that `answer[0] < i`, verify that `(j=1) < 3`, verify that `answer[1] < i`, verify that `(j=2) < 3`, verify that `answer[2] < i`, then find that `(j=3) < 3` is not true).  You will hit that worst case if `array` is sorted.  But most of the time you only do the first comparison then move to the next element.  No muss, no fuss.

How does it benchmark?

Note that if you wanted the smallest 100 elements, then you'd find it worthwhile to use a smarter data structure such as a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) to avoid the bubble sort.

Comment: For the performance test, I really struggled to benchmark your algorithm as it amazingly kept showing the same results in terms of time complexity with the recursion approach. However, when feeding both algorithms with an array of 30 million random integers ranging from 0 to 1000000000, I was able to notice a really (and probably not accurate) slight edge for your algorithm. But when a sorted array is provided the recursive approach is clearly faster (about 3.5X faster). So much value in your answer. Thanks for spreading your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really confortable with python, but I have a different approach to the problem for what it's worth.
As far as I saw, all solutions posted are `O(NM)` where N is the length of the array and M the length of the largest elements array.
Because of your specific situation where`N >> M` you could say it's `O(N)`, but the longest the inputs the more it will be `O(NM)`
I agree with @zvone that it seems you have more steps in the iterative solution, which sounds like an valid explanation to your different computing speeds.
Back to my proposal, implements binary search `O(N*logM)` with recursion:

```
import math

def binarySearch(arr, target, origin = 0):
    """ 
    Recursive binary search
    Args:
        arr (list): List of numbers to search in
        target (int): Number to search with
    Returns:
        int: index + 1 from inmmediate lower element to target in arr or -1 if already present or lower than the lowest in arr
    """
    half = math.floor((len(arr) - 1) / 2);
    if target > arr[-1]:
        return origin + len(arr)
    if len(arr) == 1 or target < arr[0]:
        return -1
    if arr[half] < target and arr[half+1] > target:
        return origin + half + 1
    if arr[half] == target or arr[half+1] == target:
        return -1
    if arr[half] < target:
        return binarySearch(arr[half:], target, origin + half)
    if arr[half] > target: 
        return binarySearch(arr[:half + 1], target, origin)
    
def findLargestNumbers(array, limit = 3, result = []):
    """ 
    Recursive linear search of the largest values in an array
    Args:
        array (list): Array of numbers to search in
        limit (int): Length of array returned. Default: 3
    Returns:
        list: Array of max values with length as limit
    """    
    if len(result) == 0:
        result = [float('-inf')] * limit
    if len(array) < 1:
        return result
    val = array[-1]
    foundIndex = binarySearch(result, val)
    if foundIndex != -1:
        result.insert(foundIndex, val)
        return findLargestNumbers(array[:-1],limit, result[1:])
    return findLargestNumbers(array[:-1], limit,result)
```

It is quite flexible and might be inspiration for a more elaborated answer.

Answer (score 0):

### The recursive solution

The recursive function goes through the list 3 times to fins the largest number and removes the largest number from the list 3 times.

```
for i in array:
    if i > max:
        ...
```

and

```
array.remove(max)
```

So, you have 3×N comparisons, plus 3x removal. I guess the removal is optimized in C, but there is again about 3×(N/2) comparisons to find the item to be removed.

So, a total of approximately 4.5 × N comparisons.

### The other solution

The other solution goes through the list only once, but each time it compares to the three elements in `sortedLargest`:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(sortedLargest))):
    ...
```

and almost each time it sorts the `sortedLargest` with these three assignments:

```
array[0] = array[1]
array[idx-1] = array[idx]
array[idx] = element
```

So, you are N times:

- calling `check`
- creating and reversing a `range(3)`
- accessing `sortedLargest[i]`
- comparing `num > sortedLargest[i]`
- calling `shift`
- comparing `idx == 0`

and about 2×N/3 times doing:

```
array[0] = array[1]
array[idx-1] = array[idx]
array[idx] = element
```

and N/3 times `array[0] = element`

It is difficult to count, but that is much more than 4.5×N comparisons.